# Image is blank when program is run

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I add an image from my WPF project and use a resource for the source, it looks ok in the designer:

[Main window in designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o9XH.png)

My code is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPlay.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPlay"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="271.107" Width="392.316">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="22,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/logo.jpg" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="137,185,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

However I find that when I run the program, although the text box can be seen, **the image is blank**.

Comment: Could you post your properties of the image?

Comment: Can you not get that from the XAML @jelleB ?  If not, what do you want to see.. the properties window in Visual Studio? This is very large.

Comment: I'm thinking about possibilities, and I would check the properties window, the xaml is okay I think.
However are you sure about this one? Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/logo.jpg" />

I mean is this working with all those comma's? It seems a bit weird to me but it can just be something I don't know

Comment: @jelleB its what you get when you select the resource in the drop-down on the Source property in the Properties window

Comment: Set the Build Action of the image file to Resource, and access it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), like `pack://application:,,,/Resources/logo.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens has the correct answer - set the build action of the image file to resource

[file properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCuqy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add useful hint to @Clemens comment: if your logo.jpg file included in the same project as control, then after typing `Source="pack://application:,,,/` you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and visual studio would show you a helper message about what file you can reference.

Comment: Taking a look at the other answer one might guess that OP's image file is actually located in a project folder named Resources.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, I did not notice that. I edited the answer.